# Waiting for async function to return true or false - how do I check return value?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

I have an async function `songAlreadyInQueue` that will return true if an ID is found in a database, false otherwise. I want to use the function like such:

```
if(!songAlreadyInQueue(ref, id)){
  // do stuff
}
```

But I know that since it's an async function, I have to wait for the result to come back before I truly know if it's true or false. What I have above is always false so I tried this:

```
songAlreadyInQueue(ref, id).then((wasFound) => {
                                console.log("wasfound = " + wasFound)
                                if(!wasFound){
                                    //do stuff
                                }
                            })
```

But that doesn't work either. What is the proper way to wait for this async function to finish? This is what my async function looks like (simplified):

```
async function songAlreadyInQueue(requestQueueRef, requestID) {
    var querye = requestQueueRef.where("id", "==", requestID)
        .get()
        .then((snap) => {
            snap.docs.forEach(doc => {
                if (doc.exists) {
                    console.log("**************FOUND REQUEST IN QUEUE ALREADY!")
                    return true
                }
            })
            return false
        })
    return querye // not sure if correct. Is this "returning a promise"?
}
```

Comment: The way you tried that "doesn't work" is basically the right way to do it. What exactly doesn't work about that way?

Comment: _"Is this "returning a promise"?"_ yes

Comment: @JosephSible wasFound is always false

Comment: That's because the return value of the `forEach` callback is not considered

Comment: @Phil ooooh so I was returning true for the forEach callback instead of returning true for songAlreadyInQueue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With an async function you should use await instead of `then()` so you're not creating another anonymous function. You are returning from an anonymous function rather than the async function. try this.

```js
async function songAlreadyInQueue(requestQueueRef, requestID) {
  var snap = await requestQueueRef.where("id", "==", requestID).get()
  var found = false;
  snap.docs.forEach(doc => {
    if (doc.exists) {
      console.log("**************FOUND REQUEST IN QUEUE ALREADY!")
      found = true
    }
  })
  return found
}
```

Comment: Using `await` or `then` isn't really the issue here but you have pointed out the problem with `forEach`

Comment: Since [`docs`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot.html#docs) is a plain array, I would suggest using `return snap.docs.some(({ exists }) => exists)` instead

Comment: using `some` isn't really an improvement, it's just sugar and an extra thing i would have to explain. an improvement would be using a real loop and returning early. that said, it absolutely is the real issue here and as i've written it it will fix the second implementation she showed in her question. if i missed something you should stop being cryptic and speak up.

Comment: `Array.prototype.some()` does return early (like your loop suggestion). That's why I suggested it

Comment: All I meant by my first comment was that you don't need to use `await` within an async function (though you then have to ask _"why bother with `async`"_). If an async function returns a promise (like in OP's question), the promise will be unwrapped correctly. Sorry, not trying to be cryptic

Comment: to each his own i guess the difference is negligible but i still would have preferred a more efficient standard loop

Comment: wait, are you saying that if i remove `await` form my answer it will still work? i will have to try that out. i didn't know. regardless, it still fixed "the real issue."

Comment: If you removed `await`, you'd need to add a `then` but yeah, it would work the same. Demo ~ https://jsfiddle.net/sjmp6kbu/

Comment: that's what i thought. you'd also need to return the promise. using async it returns a promise anyway.